# Where all the ubuntu enviroment variables stored and where is the best location to store them

Tags: command-line, bash, files, environment-variables

Well I know that I can print all environment variables but I have a hard time 
to work with them for the past year I always edit my .bashrc or .zshrc file and add in the end the environment variables like this

> export envName=someName

but is this the best scenario?

where actually all the values from

> **printenv**

coming from and where is the best location to store my environment variables like java/go/ etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those variables are set in multiple places; I won't even try to list them all.

As regards appropriate places to add or modify environment variables, it depends on the purpose. Some suggestions are mentioned on the wiki page [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) together with a general discussion about the topic.

Comment: thanks for your answer cause my main problem is that i use zsh in daily basic and store my enviroment variables in .zshrc and when i go to bash i have complitly different variables thank you for your answer

Comment: @Theodosis: Ok. If you set them system wide in e.g. `/etc/environment` they ought to be present in both.